# Errors when allocating arrays dynamically. vfscanf.c: 1898

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I'm trying to make a program that says if an array is a magic square. It worked well when creating up to 3x3 dimensions. But from 4x4 they behave badly. 5x5, or higher, I get a "Segmentation Failure (recorded core image)" error, always at the same point: mat [4] [0]. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int qm(int ** mat, int n){
    int sl = 0, sc = 0, sdP = 0, sdS = 0;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sl += mat[0][i];
        sc += mat[i][0];
        sdP += mat[i][i];
        sdS += mat[i][n-i-1];
    }


    if((sl != sc)||(sl != sdP) || (sl!= sdS)) return 0;
    else{
        for(i = 1; i < n; i++){
            int tempL = 0, tempC = 0;
            for(j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                tempC += mat[j - 1][i];
                tempL += mat[i][j - 1];
            }
            if((tempL != tempC) || (tempL != sl)) return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int ** mat, n, i, j;

    printf("\nINFORME O NUMERO N DE LINHAS E COLUNAS: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    mat = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mat[i] = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("\nINFORME MAT[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int test = qm(mat, n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        free(mat[i]);
    }
    free(mat);


    if(test) printf("\nA MATRIZ É QUADRADO MÁGICO!\n");
    else{
        printf("\nA MATRIZ NÃO É QUADRADO MÁGICO!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is some tests at gdb:

3x3 matrix:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/.../

INFORME O NUMERO N DE LINHAS E COLUNAS: 3

INFORME MAT[0][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][2]: 1

A MATRIZ É QUADRADO MÁGICO!
[Inferior 1 (process 4804) exited normally]
```

4x4 matrix:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/.../

INFORME O NUMERO N DE LINHAS E COLUNAS: 4

INFORME MAT[0][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][3]: 1
double free or corruption (out)

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:Arquivo ou diretório inexistente.
```

5x5:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/.../

INFORME O NUMERO N DE LINHAS E COLUNAS: 5

INFORME MAT[0][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][3]: 1 

INFORME MAT[2][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][0]: 1

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a538c2 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format <optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdc80, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1898
1898    vfscanf.c: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente.
```

and 6x6:

```
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/lucas/Documentos/UFF/ProgEstruturada/EXERCICIOS/labs/test 

INFORME O NUMERO N DE LINHAS E COLUNAS: 6

INFORME MAT[0][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][0]: 1

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a538c2 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdc80, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1898
1898    vfscanf.c: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente.
```

and then i tried this at gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a538c2 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdc80, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1898
#1  0x00007ffff7a5ffd8 in __isoc99_scanf (format=<optimized out>) at isoc99_scanf.c:37
#2  0x0000555555554a97 in main () at labII_exIV.c:44
(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x00007ffff7a538c2 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdc80, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1898
1898    in vfscanf.c
(gdb) list
1893    in vfscanf.c
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x00007ffff7a5ffd8 in __isoc99_scanf (format=<optimized out>) at isoc99_scanf.c:37
37  isoc99_scanf.c: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente.
(gdb) list
32  in isoc99_scanf.c
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0000555555554a97 in main () at labII_exIV.c:44
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
44              scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
(gdb) list
39      }
40  
41      for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
42          for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
43              printf("\nINFORME MAT[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
44              scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
45          }
46      }
47  
48      int test = qm(mat, n);
```

I used these commands based on a search I made about the error, I found on this site: "https://vinipsmaker.wordpress.com/2013/12/20/mug-favorito-de-cc-false-of-segmentacao/" . I saw the warning that the error is on line 44, in a call to scanf (), but I did not quite understand the problem.

I compiled with gcc in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `(int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int));` <- should be `sizeof(int *)`?

Comment: `mat = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int));` --> A less error prone way to code allocation is to use the size of the de-reference pointer rather than its type, which OP got wrong.  Use  `mat = malloc(sizeof *mat * n);`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain. Other problems may exist in code.

Comment: @immibis, yeah, thanks. Because of it I always got stuck at mat[4][0] index, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
mat = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

As `mat` is a pointer to pointer to `int`, it contains pointers to `int`. So the `malloc` operation should have `sizeof` pointer to `int`.
Change the above to:

```
mat = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
```

After this change, I tested this for 4x4, 5x5 and 6x6 matrices and it works.

Below is the output for 6X6 matrix.

```
INFORME O NUMERO N DE LINHAS E COLUNAS: 6

INFORME MAT[0][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[0][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[1][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[2][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[3][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[4][5]: 1

INFORME MAT[5][0]: 1

INFORME MAT[5][1]: 1

INFORME MAT[5][2]: 1

INFORME MAT[5][3]: 1

INFORME MAT[5][4]: 1

INFORME MAT[5][5]: 1

A MATRIZ ├ë QUADRADO M├üGICO!
```